# Accordion component in Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have an accordion component that looks like this:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, watch, toRefs } from "vue"
import { IAccordionItem } from "./types"

interface AccordionProps {
    items: IAccordionItem[]
    toggleAll?: boolean
    keyComponent?: boolean
    headerClass?: string
}

const props = defineProps<AccordionProps>()

const { items } = toRefs(props)
const entireCollapseModel = ref<boolean[]>([])

watch(
    items,
    (newItems) => {
        entireCollapseModel.value = newItems.map(
            (item) => item.value.checked === true
        )
    },
    { immediate: true, deep: true }
)


function toggleCollapse(index: number): void {
    entireCollapseModel.value[index] = !entireCollapseModel.value[index]
}
</script>

<template>
    <div
        id="accordionComponent"
        class="accordion"
    >
        <div
            v-for="(item, index) in items"
            :key="item.key"
            class="accordion-item"
        >
            <h2
                class="accordion-header one-px-top-margin"
                @click.capture="toggleCollapse(index)"
            >
                <button
                    :aria-controls="'collapse-' + index"
                    :aria-expanded="entireCollapseModel[index]"
                    :data-bs-target="'#collapse-' + index"
                    :class="headerClass"
                    class="accordion-button collapsed"
                    data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                    type="button"
                >
                    <slot
                        :slot-props="{ header: item.key, content: item.value }"
                        name="header"
                    />
                </button>
            </h2>
            <div
                :id="'collapse-' + index"
                aria-labelledby="headingOne"
                class="accordion-collapse collapse"
                data-bs-parent="#accordionComponent"
            >
                <div class="accordion-body">
                    <slot
                        :slot-props="{ header: item.key, content: item.value }"
                        name="content"
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Which is implemented like this:

```
<accordion
    :header-class="'p-2'"
    :items="[{ key: 'TEST 1', value: {} }]"
    :toggle-all="false"
>
    <template #header="{ slotProps }">
        {{ slotProps.header }}
    </template>
    <template #content="{ slotProps }">
        ...
    </template>
</accordion>

<accordion
    :header-class="'p-2'"
    :items="[
        { key: 'TEST 2', value: {} },
    ]"
    :toggle-all="false"
>
    <template #header="{ slotProps }">
        {{ slotProps.header }}
    </template>
    <template #content="{ slotProps }">
        ...
    </template>
</accordion>
```

But I can't get them to work independently. When I toggle one they all toggle. What am I doing wrong here? I have tried console logging toggleCollapse and it is only printing the item that I clicked on yet they all toggle.

Comment: Please, provide a demo as there's a fair amount of code, it makes sense to debug it rather than solve this on paper. From what I see you don't use proper `items` value, it's a new array on every rerender, it's the only thing that's in common in these two accordions. They don't share a state.